# Контроль запуска программ

Tags: c++

Утилита должна перехватывать команду запуска программ. Должна быть обеспечена работа в режиме чёрного и белого списков. Режим чёрного списка – разрешено запускать всё, кроме программ из чёрного списка. Режим белого списка – запрещено запускать всё, кроме программ из белого списка. При разработке программы Применение административных политик, встроенных в Windows запрещается.
Можете дать несколько советов по выполнению данной работы

Comment: BalgenOS и PopovAV ваяете?

Comment: вы бы для начала написали свои навыки, а то как вам можно давать советы не зная вашей базы?

Comment: Один из способов решения задачи это [установка хуков](https://habr.com/ru/company/icl_services/blog/324718/), а потом хуками ловить какое то подмножество из WinApi вызовов, подмножество функций отвечающих за запуск приложений. Получится то же самое, что делают например Антивирусы, возможно разве что они ещё вовлекают уровень драйвера.